# Why my ajax request is giving 500 internal error in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to varify username when new user is entered. and i am trying to use ajax so user can given correct username in the field.

**form**

```
<form role="form">
     <input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

        <div class="form-row">
             <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
             </div>

             <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="username">User Name</label> <label id="username_message" style="float: right;margin-right: 10px"></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="User Name">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
             </div>

             <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="pass">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
             </div>


        </div>

        <div class="text-center">
             <button type="submit" name="submit" id="insert" class="btn btn-primary my-4">{{ __('Sign in') }}</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

**ajax request**

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#username').keyup(function (){
            var token = $('#token').val();
            var username = $('#username').val();

            if (username !== '') {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: '{{ route('verifyUserName') }}',
                    data: {
                        '_token': token,
                        'username': username,
                    },

                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log('ok');

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

**route**

```
Route::get('verifyUserName', [\App\Http\Controllers\SuperAdminController::class, 'verifyUserName'])->name('verifyUserName');
```

**controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class SuperAdminController extends Controller
{
    private function verifyUserName(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            return response()->json(['code'=>'200']);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried also the **post** method but the result is same. it is giving me this error.

**error**

```
jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost/Project/verifyUserName?_token=duyglp2z8DhpAJ8vnI4rd1Vrdjnqzq1zw1ythiZa&username=g 500 (Internal Server Error)     

jquery.min.js:2
```

i am very confused what is the problem. please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: The 500 error indicates a problem on the laravel server end. What do you see if you attempt to call that path in the browser directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function verifyUserName(Request $request){

    if($request->ajax())
    {
        return response()->json(['code'=>'200']);
    }
}
```

try `public function` instead

Comment: $users = User::where('user_name', "==", $username)->get();       i am trying to get exact match. i have tried above code but its not giving me exact match

Answer (score 0):

You may be submitting ajax data to the wrong route type and even the wrong URL (404). So first double-check the path you are submitting to. Second, check whether the route accepts “Post” or “Get” data type. Because submitting post data via Get method or vice versa will results in Laravel ajax giving 500 Internal Server Error.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">

var request = $.ajax({
    url: "script.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {  _token : <?php Session::token() ?>},
    dataType: "html" 
});
```

DATA TYPE RETURNED:

If you are returning Boolean and your ajax code is set for Json or any other data type then chances are that you will stumble upon the internal server error. Try to set the data type for all ajax responses to JSON. If you are using jQuery then set dataType to XML, JSON, script, or HTML like this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "/action",
    method: "POST",
    data: { id : userId },
    dataType: "json"
});
```